# passing down functions correctly for onSubmit and handleChange on a form

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to handle navigation around my application. I want to include a link back to the form component from displayweather using conditional statements. I can get the form to show correctly, however when you press submit on the form it just refreshes back to the Form  under App

I am trying to pass the functions down from App to Navbar which holds a second instance of the Form
However, using react dev tools the functions are still showing as undefined?
Here is a gist of the code:
https://gist.github.com/dhuang612/6c683b6ccd0ce6299631db76ed76ccd7

The two functions I am trying to hand down from App

```
handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
     });
  };
  //handles submit on the form and runs the api call
 onSubmit = e => {
   e.preventDefault();
   this.fetchWeatherData();
    this.setState({ fetchedweatherdata: !this.state.fetchedweatherdata }, () =>
  console.log(this.state.fetchedweatherdata)
   );
 };
```

this is how I am trying to pass the functions down to this second instance of form

```
    <DisplayWeather
        currentweather={this.state.currentweather}
        currentforecast={this.state.currentforecast}
        currenttime={this.state.currenttime}
        weatherIcon={this.state.weatherIcon}
        hourlyWeather={this.state.hourlyWeather}
      />
      <Navbar fetchedweatherdata={this.state.fetchedweatherdata}>
        <Form
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          {...this.state}
          onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
        />
      </Navbar>

     and this is how I am trying to call the functions on the form
      return (
         <div>
           {!this.state.fetchedweatherdata ? (
          <div>
           <button onClick={this.resetState}>return to form</button>
        </div>
           ) : (
         <Form onChange={handleChange} {...this.state} onSubmit=
          {onSubmit} />
           )}
        </div>
```

I am not getting any error messages, the screen refreshes and reloads the origin Form under App, I would like the application to re-send out the api request and show current weather for the new location. Please see gist to see all the code together.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that you did not pass nothing to Navbar itself. 
I did put a codesandbox up for you, please, for the future question if there is more code included try to do the same with codesandbox, this can save lifes!

[Here is the mentioned sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-microservice-6x7xm)